# Docker build not recognizing && in RUN command

Tags: docker

When I execute `docker build .` in the directory with the Dockerfile below, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Unknown instruction: &&
```

Why doesn't the `&&` in my Dockerfile work? I see it used all the time in other Dockerfiles to string together commands.

I'm using Docker version 1.13.1, build 47e2230/1.13.1 on Fedora 30.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    && mkdir -p /opt/google/
    && curl -sSL "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.5.0.21/android-studio-ide-191.5791312-linux.tar.gz" -o /opt/google/android-studio.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf /opt/google/android-studio.tar.gz \
    && cd /opt/google/android-studio/bin/./studio.sh \
    && rm /opt/google/android-studio.tar.gz \
    && echo "PATH=${PATH}:/opt/google/android-studio/bin" >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: Missing "\" after `mkdir -p /opt/google/`, perhaps? Also, I find the `curl` on its own line rather disturbing.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing "\". This is why I should stop looking at text after midnight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `&& mkdir -p /opt/google/` is missing a `\` at the end.